# Redirecting stdout in code that modifies the Cursor

Tags: c#, .net, stdout, io-redirection

I have a program (no source) that I want to redirect the stdout and strerr off so I can parse the progress indicator and show a progress in the application that's calling it.

The problem is this application has calles to Console.Clear(), SetWindowSize, Cursor.Top etc.

These seem to break redirection and crash the application. I've managed to get it to work by NOPing these calls in the il code, but this ofcourse is more of a hack than anything else.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to redirect the STDs without removing these calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you are stuck.

You can't use any of those fancy features in a redirected port.

Comment: Damn.. I was afraid of this. I'll give a few things a try tomorrow. If they don't succeed I'll mark this as the answer (unless someone brews up some nice black magic ofcourse) :)

Comment: @Phyx: I would love a better answer too :)

Comment: hadn't had the chance to take a look at it yet. When I do I'll post something here If I get it to work, Cheers

Comment: I did find a way to do it in the end, By polling the console's BufferInfo I can read the text that's being printed to the console and just hide the console window. Same technique as described at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection